# How to debug Django templates using PyDev?

Tags: django, debugging, templates, pydev

I have been able to get the PyDev debugger to work for .py files in my Django project--however the breakpoints on lines with template tags in my .html templates are never triggered. Does PyDev support template debugging? Are there any workarounds that people have come up with?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the PyDev debugger only works with Python files.

Comment: I would use django debug toolbar to debug the context.

Answer (score 0):

PyDev has no custom support for debugging django templates.

Still, if you want, you can do something as a breakpoint to check some variable through a template tag.

I.e.:

In your project create a project/templatetags/pydev_debug.py (that folder also needs the `__init__.py`)

Then add the code to that file:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def pydev_debug(*args):
    # In pydev, doing pydevd|ctrl+space will show template for pydevd.settrace() 
    # with code below with the proper path to emulate breakpoint.
    import sys;sys.path.append(r'path/to/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev/pysrc')
    import pydevd;pydevd.settrace() #Emulate breakpoint
```

Then in your template add {% load pydev_debug %}

And to get to the breakpoint add {{ my_var|pydev_debug }}